# How to revert Master branch to upstream

Tags: git, github

I have forked a git repository and setup upstream. I've made some changes in Master branch and committed and pushed to github.

Now what should I do to abandon all my changes in Master branch and make it identical to the upstream's master branch?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

(I'm assuming that the changes that you now want to ignore are at your `origin` remote, you're on your `master` branch, and you want to revert to the contents of the `upstream` remote)

Firstly, reset your working copy to the upstream master:

```
git remote update
# the double hyphen ensures that upstream/master is
# considered as a revision and not confused as a path
git reset --hard upstream/master --
```

Then push this new branch-head to your origin repository, ignoring the fact that it won't be a fast-forward:

```
git push origin +master
```

Comment: May also need to run `git remote add upstream <upstream_repo_url>` if you forked the branch using GitHub.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `+` in `git push origin +master`? Is it the same as just `git push origin master`?

Comment: @bluenote10 They're not the same. The `+` is what tells git to "[ignore] the fact that it won't be a fast-forward". It's a bit like doing a `git push --force`, but it only applies to that specific ref.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I did a git status after it has items that have been modified. I'm going to have to wipe and start over. Git is extremely difficult to understand.

Comment: What if I have some commits on another branch, say `working` that I want to keep, would this wipe out everything?

Comment: @mehmet No, it changes only the branch you're on.

Comment: @mehmet you'll probably want to switch to the `working` branch and do `git rebase master`.

Comment: It's a bit easy to miss the 2nd line in this solution (eg `git reset --hard`) since the 1st line is followed by 2 comments. I missed it. Maybe putting the comments last would make it clearer