# Clear my master branch and send a clean pull request

Tags: git, github

I am new to use git and here is the question. I have forked a repo and get one patch merged to the original project already without any trouble. After that, a major release of that project is out, I do a pull the upstream master to merge my master branch with new updates. But after I have done that, I try that whether I can make a clean pull request after I have pushed my orign master after the merge. The result turns to be that I have modified files(not modified by me) and commits logs from others in the pull request page. I think that is a little strange.

I think I have messed up some important steps when I update with the upstream. If I do not want to delete my fork and refork the repo, How can I do to clean my repo to sync with the upstream master and do not hurt my original commit history? (I do not want the commit history on and after I pull and merge the upstream master)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How to revert Master branch to upstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134960/git-how-to-revert-master-branch-to-upstream)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered git [rebase](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/31/intro-to-rebase.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Can you shade me some light what does the problem come from?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, as I'm still a Git n00b, but I don't think it's a problem. There were changes made upstream and you pulled them into your branch. Your branch was forked off of a particular commit and you're now asking the repository to merge your branch (which contains those commits) back in. The merge should be seamless, but you'll see those commits in your pull request's diff.