# How to tidy up a git branch / pull request full of unintended commits?

Tags: git, angularjs, github, github-for-windows

I am a casual contributor to the Angular.js project.

Months ago, I created a new feature branch in my local repo to test an enhancement, and when I was happy with it, I sent a pull request. There were problems however, and I never did get it into an acceptable state (though I did eventually find [the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5926) that was blocking me).

Recently, I revisited this branch hoping to fix it up. I tried to bring my local repo up to date using GitHub for Windows, but in doing so I mucked this branch up quite a bit: My local branch now contains hundreds of commits from the upstream repo, and worst of all my original (abandoned) pull request now includes all these commits! As in, *"jamesdaily referenced this issue from a commit in jamesdaily/angular.js 4 months ago"* on many different issues.

I've since brought my local master up to date [via these commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134960/git-how-to-revert-master-branch-to-upstream).

But my goal is to remove the clutter I've caused to the main angular/angular.js repo. I'm willing to take whatever actions are necessary. I have no outstanding changes that I care to retain in my local repo.

How can I tidy this up?

Here is the branch in question: https://github.com/jamesdaily/angular.js/tree/deeplinking-hash-url-fix

And the mucked up pull request: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4191

Here is an example issue where my branch is leaving notes everywhere: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5247

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch at the point where you want to start up (keep the original for backup, until *long* after you are satisfied nothing broke).

Use `git cherry-pick` to get the changes you want into your new branch. Afterwards you can go in and clean up with `git rebase --interactive`, which allows you to squash commits together, split them, edit them, reorder them, ... in general go wild. Make sure the commits in your mangled history make sense, and declare your cleaned up version as official.

Comment: Hundreds of commits owned by others got pulled in and referenced when I pushed the wrong buttons / commands in GitHub's GUI client. I'd like to remove all those other commits that occurred after my last personal commit: a363fcae2fe5e32c19e1e69f762e3f1bd13faf8b .  My primary goal is to get rid of all those "jamesdaily referenced this issue from a commit in jamesdaily/angular.js on Jan 26" that appear on the official angular/angular.js repo.  Would deleting my local branch help at all?