# Git commit squashed when merging upstream, how do I update my local repo

Tags: git, github, merge

I made a few commits in a local repo, pushed those to the remote and created a Pull Request to the upstream master.  Those commits were squashed when the PR was merged.

```
$ git commit A
$ git push origin master
$ git commit B
$ git push origin master
```

Create PR, squash and merge into upstream master

Then when I do ...

```
$ git pull upstream master
```

It does a merge instead of a fast forward since the commit is different. How do I update my local repo to match the upstream master history after commits have been changed/squashed upstream?

I ended up doing the following ...

```
$ git reset HEAD~2 --hard
$ git pull upstream master
$ git push origin master --force
```

To match my history, but I'm hoping there's a much cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135023/4594973), and noted by others, you should run the command below after fetching/updating:

```
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

More importantly, however, is knowing how to avoid running yourself into a corner.

#### Avoiding the Problem

To avoid this problem in the future, **you should *always* use *separate* branches for development**. You posted:

> ```
> $ git commit A
> $ git push origin master
> $ git commit B
> $ git push origin master
> ```

From your example above, it looks like you were using your `master` branch for development. That's a big **no-no** and this seems to be the *real* cause of your problems. Instead, do the following:

```
git checkout -b changes-for-pull-request
# hack hack
git commit
git push origin changes-for-pull-request
# hack hack
git commit
git push origin changes-for-pull-request
```

You do *not* merge your `changes-for-pull-request` branch into your `master` branch. Instead, you send the pull request and point them to your separate topic branch to pull from. You could even rebase your work with their latest to make it easier on them. For example, when you're getting ready to issue your pull request you can `rebase` as follows:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master  # you never make changes here, so not a problem
git rebase master changes-for-pull-request  # fix conflicts, if any
git push origin changes-for-pull-request
```

Send the pull request and point them to your `changes-for-pull-request` branch. When they merge it into *their* master, it's simply a matter of you doing a `git pull upstream master` again and you won't have issues.

#### Cleaning up After Yourself

Since by now your pull request has been merged upstream and has made its way into your own `master` branch, you can safely delete your `changes-for-pull-request` branch locally and in your own `origin` to clean up.

```
git push --delete origin changes-for-pull-request
git branch -d changes-for-pull-request  # note lower-case "-d"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any local changes you wanna save, you can just reset your local branch to match the remote.

First, get the new data from remote with

```
git fetch upstream
```

Second, after double checking that you are in your local master branch

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

That would reset your local branch to match the one at the remote.

Comment: If you DO have changes that you would want to save, you can stash them first, do the hard reset and then pop the stash.